# How to define null or lambda in CFG?

Tags: python, nltk

```
 grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP Q |Q NP VP|
NP -> Det N | Det N PP
VP -> V NP | V NP PP
PP -> P NP
NP -> 'I'
N -> 'man' | 'park' | 'telescope' | 'dog'|'car'
Det -> 'the' | 'a'
P -> 'in' | 'with'
V -> 'saw'
Q ->'As'|null
""")
sent = 'I saw a car in the park'.split()

parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar, trace=2)
t=  parser.parse(sent)
for tree in t:
 #print(tree)
 tree.draw()
```

In the above sentence 'As' is optional.How do I write null or lambda in nltk grammer?

Comment: In this particular grammar, you could eliminate the need for Q by replacing the first line with:  S -> 'As' NP VP | NP VP 'As' | NP VP

Comment: @ScottHunter consider Q can be of multiple values Q->'But'|'As'|"when"|null .I want to know how to write null in the grammar.

Comment: @gully You can represent by writing "nothing". For instance, `S -> 'X' | ` matches both `""` and `"X"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we broke up `Q` into *null* and all the rest, `Qx`.  Then you could re-write the rule for `S` as:

S -> Qx NP VP | NP VP Qx | NP VP

and not need `Q` at all.

In fact, unless you need to accept the empty string, any CFG can be transformed to have no "null"s.

Comment: yes this is a possibility but i wanted to know how to write s-> null  in the grammar. Also if my productions increase, which will,then it becomes complex.